# Using a composite foreign key from an intersection entity as a primary key?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have four tables, 2 which are separate entities, an intersection entity which links those two together and third table which makes reference to the intersection entity. Here's the structure of what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
    primaryKeyA   number(4) ,
    PRIMARY KEY (primaryKeyA) );

CREATE TABLE tableB (
    primaryKeyB   number(4) ,
    PRIMARY KEY(primaryKeyB) );

CREATE TABLE intersectionTable (
    primaryKeyA   number(4) ,
    primaryKeyB   number(4) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (primaryKeyA) REFERENCES tableA ,
    FOREIGN KEY (primaryKeyB) REFERENCES tableB ,
    PRIMARY KEY (primaryKeyA, primaryKeyB) );

CREATE TABLE tableC (
    primaryKeyC   number(4) ,
    primaryKeyA   number(4) ,
    primaryKeyB   number(4) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (primaryKeyA) REFERENCES intersectionTable ,
    FOREIGN KEY (primaryKeyB) REFERENCES intersectionTable ,
    PRIMARY KEY (primaryKeyA, primaryKeyB, primaryKeyC) );
```

The problem is that every time I create `tableC` I recieve the following error from oracle:

> ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

I'll need to make sure that `tableC` can reference the composite key in `intersectionTable`, which I thought I had done with my FOREIGN KEY constraints. I did change the constraints in `tableC` to:

```
FOREIGN KEY (primaryKeyA) REFERENCES tableA ,
FOREIGN KEY (primaryKeyB) REFERENCES tableB ,
```

however on querying the database, I found that it wasn't utilising the composite key created in `intersectionTable`, which is required of me.

Any help would be awesome.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE tableC
    ( primaryKeyC   number(4)
    , primaryKeyA   number(4)
    , primaryKeyB   number(4)
    , FOREIGN KEY (primaryKeyA,primaryKeyB)
          REFERENCES intersectionTable (primaryKeyA,primaryKeyB) 
    , PRIMARY KEY (primaryKeyA, primaryKeyB, primaryKeyC)
    )
    ;
```